# upgrading to spring 3.0 problem with interceptorNames

Tags: spring, spring-3

I am trying to upgrade to Spring 3.0 and i have the following issues:

- Finding the dependencies. People recommend using maven, but id rather not try to learn how to use maven/install it if the jars are available somewhere for download.
- The following bean declaration is now longer valid but i dont know how to fix it:

> ```
> <bean id="service"
>    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
>
>   <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.service.SomeService" /> 
>   <property name="target">
>         <bean class="com.service.SomeServiceImpl">
>         </bean>
>   </property>
>   <property name="interceptorNames"> 
>     <list> 
>       <value>hibernateInterceptor</value> 
>
>     </list> 
>   </property>
> </bean>
> ```

The complaint is that `<property name="interceptorNames">` is no longer supported and should be done some other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arr you referring to the following mention in the docs for `setInterceptorNames`?

> NOTE: Specifying a target bean as final name in the "interceptorNames" list is deprecated and will be removed in a future Spring version. Use the "targetName" property instead.

This refers to an odd feature of this property where the last item in the list of interceptors can actually be the intercepted bean itself, rather than being an actual interceptor. This is confusing, though, and discouraged - you're supposed to specify the target using the `targetName` property.

So `interceptorNames` is still the way to specify interceptors.

Comment: so..  property name="interceptorNames" targetName="hibernateInterceptor"  />

Comment: @mkoryak: No, the bean definition in your original question is correct as it is; the documentation is referring to an obscure usage of `interceptorNames`, but your usage is fine.